# \includegraphics not working with xelatex for PDFs with images in them

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex

I switched to using xelatex so I could use a specific font, but now some images don't render.

Here's a simplified example that illustrates the failure:

```
% The next lines tell TeXShop to typeset with xelatex, and to open and save the source with Unicode encoding.
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node{\includegraphics{image.pdf}}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If I omit the three lines at the top, I can see my image centered at the top of the page.  With xelatex, I get a blank page.

UPDATE: There is something about including a specific PDF graphic that will render with LaTeX, but not XeTeX... below is some more detail about what works and what doesn't.  Looking for a less manual work-around than the one detailed below!

This works for a PDF with simple vector graphics, as generated from:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikz [blend group=screen] {
  \fill[red!90!black]   ( 90:.6) circle (1);
  \fill[green!80!black] (210:.6) circle (1);
  \fill[blue!90!black] (330:.6) circle (1);
}
\end{document}
```

This also works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, landscape, margin=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \makebox[\linewidth]{
    \includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{green-eyed-kitty.jpg}
  }
\end{document}
```

Using this p[ublic domain image](http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/60000/nahled/green-eyed-kitty.jpg)

[image: green eyed kitty]

[This image](https://github.com/mightyverse/tex-cards/blob/master/assets/single-starter-background.pdf) doesn't appear, but if I wrap it the same LaTeX and render a new PDF it works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=3.25in, paperheight=2in, margin=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \makebox[\linewidth]{
    \includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{assets/single-starter-background.pdf}
  }
\end{document}
```

The PDF that I'm trying to include was created from InDesign.  Is there some kind of preprocess I can bake into my LaTeX script, so I don't have to pre-process everything manually each time?

When I run analyze the file with Adobe Acrobat Pro, Tools > Print Production > Preflight, it shows some errors:

[image]

I suppose I can instruct the designers on my team to export PDFs with PDF 1.3 (Acrobat 4) compatibility in the future.  The default in my copy of InDesign is 1.4, looks like latest is 1.7.

Is the PDF version compatibility for Xetex documented somewhere?

Comment: I do not know xetex but don't you need **\usepackage{graphicx}**?

Comment: I was adding the smallest amount of code to reproduce the issue.  To render fonts, the sample code had \usepackage{graphicx} and
\usepackage{amssymb}, but adding them doesn't make the image render (and with regular LaTeX those aren't needed).

Comment: Your code works for me with xelatex, but I don't have your `image.pdf` file. It is possible that something is wrong in this file. Check with another pdf image.

Comment: I have no problems with your code. I wonder about the image file you're trying to include.

Comment: @jon added some more detail including a link to the PDF.  There is definitely something about my image file that is not compatible with xetex.  At this point, I'm hoping for a work-around so I can auto-convert PDFs made with InDesign into something xetex can render -- if not something that will actually work in xetex.

Comment: OK, I can reproduce that: no image with XeTeX, images with LuaTeX and pdfTeX. Moreover, if I convert the image to PS and back (i.e., `pdftops`, then `ps2pdf`), the image does appear XeTeX. (Thus the problem is getting out of my depth....)

Comment: try pdfinfo utility on the pdfs that work or don't work, in particular the pdf version of the files

Comment: @DavidCarlisle pdfinfo utility? do you have a link to that?

Comment: well try `xelatex --output-driver="xdivpdfmx -V 7 -q" foo.tex` see this thread..  http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2015-July/037149.html

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with your file, but I know how to fix it. Compile this file `\documentclass{standalone}\usepackage{graphicx} \begin{document} \includegraphics{single-starter-background.pdf} \end{document}` with `pdflatex`, and then use the resulting pdf image inside `xelatex` source.

Comment: @Kpym yep, that is the manual work-around I mentioned in my update to the bug.  since this seems like it is a compatibility problem with this particular PDF, I've reported it as a bug here:  https://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/bugs/119/

Comment: @Ultrasaurus I'm not sure that this is a xetex bug. You know in a pdf file you have different box limits (CropBox, MediaBox,ArtBox,...), if one of them used by xetex (but not used by pdflatex) is not properly set for example this may result in badly cropped output. Have you checked your PDF file with Acrobat Preflight if it is a valid one ?

Comment: @Kpym thanks for pointing me to the Acrobat Preflight tool.  I updated the issue with the results... would appreciate any details on what this means!

Comment: @Ultrasaurus all these "errors" in Adobe Preflight are not really errors. There are different PDF standards and your file doesn't meets them, but a standard PDF produced by LaTeX doesn't meets them either. PDF v1.4 is the default one for xetex and pdftex I think, so this is not the problem.

Comment: @Ultrasaurus Just for info : your file is not produced with Illustrator but with Photoshop and is PDF v1.6. When I convert it to PDF v1.4 it works with xetex for me.

Comment: @Kpym: I was having the same issue, and your "standalone" solution worked