# Included graphics in TiKZ with XeLaTeX get displaced

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, debugging, includegraphics

I have a problem with `\includegraphics` within TikZ with XeLaTeX, namely that the images get displaced.

This is similar to the problem described in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/280485/28608), but the symptoms are different. Moreover, this problem appeared when I switched from Ubuntu’s TeX Live to a manually installed minimalistic TeX Live 2019, which suggests that I may be missing some package or I made some mistake when installing (I haven’t tried a full installation yet). Note that no error or otherwise helpful message is thrown.

#### Minimal example

It seems that any PDF image will cause the problem, but just so we are on the same page, I compile the following to obtain an `image.pdf` to use. (It doesn’t seem to matter whether I compile with `pdflatex` or `xelatex`.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \Huge Here is some text.
\end{document}
```

The main file is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node{
                \includegraphics[scale=1]{image.pdf}
            };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I compile this file once with `xelatex` (left) and once with `pdflatex` (right) and everything seems normal:

[image: example for scale=1]

Now, I change the size of the image to `scale=2`:

[image: example for scale=2]

And finally for `scale=3`, the included image has completely sailed off the page:

[image: example for scale=3]

This problem vanishes when I remove the TikZ wrapper. What could be the reason for this and how can I fix it?

Comment: What happens if you use mm instead of em as a unit?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Not much, but using yet another unit made me discover something interesting: Please see my edit.

Comment: Hm. Interesting. It looks like a pgf bug, but needs some investigating.

Comment: It is clearly a pgf bug in the newest version. Reverting to the previous one resolves the problem. I made a bug report https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/708

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks for finding that out. Now I just need to figure out how to obtain and install the last version of PGF …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a [bug in PGF](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/708) that has now been fixed.